# Change CSS via Jquery - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to complete a simple function, what is wrong with this code?

Basically I'm trying to overlay a span, with the exact same width as its containing `<a>` link. So I want the black span box (in example) as wide as the containing grey box.

```js
function vg() {
    if ($("body").hasClass("work-page")) {
        var a = $(".projTitle").width();
        $(".subtitle").css({
            width: a + "px",
        })
    }
```

```css
li {
 position:relative;
}
li a.projTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 15px auto 0px;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-weight:300;
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:18px;
}
li .subtitle {
    font-size:10px;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: .8;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 83px;
    width:auto;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body class="work-page">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="css3Animate projTitle" href="work/project/index.html">The Project<span class="css3Animate subtitle">subtext span</span></a>
  </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So where do you call the method?

Comment: what is wrong with this code? nothing -- https://jsfiddle.net/xu8809f5/ -- you created a function but you don't know how to run it. functions dont magically run by themselfs unless you call (run) them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you called the function at all ? Works for me if i call `vg()`

```js
function vg() {
     if ($("body").hasClass("work-page")) {
         var a = $(".projTitle").width();
          console.log(a)
              $(".subtitle").css({
                width: a + "px",
             })
              
  }
    }
    
    vg()
```

```css
li {
 position:relative;
}
li a.projTitle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 15px auto 0px;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-weight:300;
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:18px;
}
li .subtitle {
    font-size:10px;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: .8;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 83px;
    width:auto;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="work-page">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="css3Animate projTitle" href="work/project/index.html">The Project<span class="css3Animate subtitle">subtext span</span></a>
  </li>
```

I would be wary about the code you are using.

For example, if you have more elements with the same class as you've selected, i.e projTitle, JQuery's `.width()` will get the first element of the array as selecting something by class ($('.'+className)) will return an array of elements with that class.

Where as if you select something by ID, as nothing should share an ID, you'll be certain to get the correct element :)

Comment: Ah yes, ran into this problem. Is there a way that I can set the width of each instance of .subtitle, by its parent container (a.projTitle), without having to specify separate ID tags for each instance? Thanks!

Comment: set width to 100% in css

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function. You could call it in your script tag, without referencing in the html as suggested in the comment below it is better to attach the handler inside a script tag instead instead of inline

```
$(".css3Animate").click(function(){
    vg();;
})
```

or else you can call the function inline by using `onclick="vg()"`

```
 <a class="css3Animate projTitle" href="#" onclick="vg()">The Project<span class="css3Animate subtitle">subtext span</span></a>
```

See the [jsfiddle here with it working](https://jsfiddle.net/gyy22ytL/)

Comment: Or, more ideally, attach the handler inside a script tag instead instead of inline.